# Liferay add service action not associated for dojo GET/PUT/POST?

Tags: javascript, json, http, dojo, liferay

I must be missing something small here, but I'm trying to insert a new MBMessage into a liferay CE 6.1 database using the JSON Web Service API.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
var sourceUrl = "/api/secure/jsonws/mbmessage/add-message/group-id/10180/" + 
    "category-id/0/subject/test/body/test/format/bbcode/" + 
    "input-streamov-ps/%5B%5D/anonymous/false/priority/0/allow-pingbacks/true";

request.post(sourceUrl, {
    handleAs: "json"
}).then(
    function(data) {
        //do something
    },
    function(error){
        //do something else
    }
);
```

I get the following error in the tomcat console:

```
ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-10][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:114] java.lang.RuntimeException: No JSON web service action associated with path /mbmessage/add-message and method POST for /
java.lang.RuntimeException: No JSON web service action associated with path /mbmessage/add-message and method POST for /
```

I am authenticated and I have been able to get it to work at my localhost:8080/api/jsonws but no dice with the JS/dojo implementation.  I have tried using HTTP PUT and HTTP GET in addition to POST but with no luck.  Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to work around this by creating my own custom service method and calling that instead, but if anyone has any suggestions as to how to fix the approach outlined above I'd love to hear them!

Comment: Remove secure from /api/secure/jsonws/... . You can see what path should be by looking at the http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws. Search for add-message in /. Use the gui to execute a request. By doing so you will see a URL Example.